# Getting information of user after loggingIn in node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, passport-local

I am using passport-local to authenticate users for my website.

```
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) { 

            User.findOne({'local.username': username}, function(err, user) {
                if(err)
                    return done(err);
                if(!user){
                    console.log('User Not Found with username ');
                    return done(null, false);   
                }
                if(!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                    console.log('Invalid Password');
                    return done(null, false); // redirect back to login page
                }
                console.log('Successfully logged in user ');
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ));
```

And this is how it routes:

```
router.get('/success', function(req, res){
        res.send({state: 'success', user: req.user ? req.user : null});
    });
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
    }));
router.get('/profile', function(req, res){
        res.render('profile.ejs', { user: req.user });
    });
```

This is how I am calling the above login function in a .ts file:

```
let data = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
  };

  this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/login', data).pipe(
    map(res => res.json())
).subscribe(res=> {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Login Successful!',
    subTitle: 'You are logged in',
    buttons: ['Okay']
  });
  alert.present();
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/profile', res);
```

Here I should get all of the user's data while user logs in res, Shouldn't I? If not so then how to get all of the user's data while logging in and send it to /profile?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the data?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that line. I am trying to send it to /profile with this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/profile', res);

Comment: How do you expect this flow to be? As I don't see anything happening in your profile router other than forwarding your request to `profile.ejs`. I mean how do you expect user data here?

Answer (score 0):

Hope your passport and model is configured properly.

Try something like -

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    // HOME PAGE 
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
    });


    // LOGIN 
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {    
        res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
    });

    // PROFILE SECTION 
    app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });    

};

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // user authentication in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // user not authenticated, take to home page
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

And then something like -

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to profile 
        failureRedirect : '/login'
    }));
```

You can try accessing user object inside your template like - something similar to `<%= user.local.email %>` depending on your template engine.